# Java Netty Cross channel communication failed

Tags: java, sockets, netty, nio

I hope to realize the following communication among three parties:
[image]

The communication process is:
(1) A sends M1 to B
(2) B, after receiving M1, forwards to C
(3) C, after receiving M1, responds with M2
(4) B, after receiving M2, forward M2 to A
(5) Finally A output M2

I have realized all the code using Netty, but currently the problem is:
after B receiving M2 from C, I tried to **put M2 to the communication channel between A and B**, hoping that A can directly receive it, but it seems it ***fails***. Thanks in advance if anyone can help, and the following is a basic implementation of my code:

1. A.java sends `M1` to B, and AHandler.java listens on what sent by B:

```
// A.java

import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.*;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // loop group
        EventLoopGroup loopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        // create bootstrap
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        try {
            bootstrap.group(loopGroup)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new AHandler());
                        }
                    });
            ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect("localhost", 6002).sync();
            future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            loopGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

```
// AHandler.java

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;

public class AHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        String M1 = "M1";
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(M1, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        // !!! Hope to receive what B forwards from C, namely M2, but cannot receive it
        ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
        System.out.println("B responds receipt: " + buf.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

2. `B` listens on port `6002`, and after receiving `M1` from `A`, forwards to `C` by creating a new channel between `B` and `C`:

```
// B.java

import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;

public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create thread pool
        // create Boss group : receiving client connection
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        // create work group: network read and communication
        EventLoopGroup workGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        // create start class
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();

        try {
            bootstrap.group(bossGroup, workGroup) // set thread group
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class) //set channel
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024) // set the number of thread connections
                    //.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true) // keep connection
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new BHandler());
                        }
                    }).childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
            System.out.println("----- B is online -----");
            ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.bind(6002).sync();
            channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

```
// BHandler.java (as the server end between A and B)

import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.*;
import io.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroup;
import io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;
import io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor;

public class BHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    public static ChannelGroup channelGroup = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);

    public static Channel Channel_AB = null;

    public void BForwardM1() {
        EventLoopGroup loopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        try {
            bootstrap.group(loopGroup)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new BCHandler());
                        }
                    });
            ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect("localhost", 6003).sync();
            future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            loopGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        // Add channel_AB to channel group
        Channel channel_AB = ctx.channel();
        Channel_AB = channel_AB;
        channelGroup.add(channel_AB);

        System.out.println("Received from A: " + channel_AB.remoteAddress() + ", channel ID: " + channel_AB.id());
        ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
        String M1_From_A = buf.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("M1_From_A: " + M1_From_A);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        // B forwards M1 to C
        BForwardM1();
    }

}
```

```
// BCHandler.java (as the client end of between B and C)

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.*;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;

public class BCHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        String M1 = "M1";
        // B forwards M1 to C
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(M1, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
        // C responds with M2
        String M2 = buf.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("Receive C's respond: " + M2);

        // !!! Trying to put M2 to AB's channel
        BHandler.channelGroup.forEach(ch -> {
            if (ch != null) {
                ch.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(M2, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
            } else {
                System.out.println("No available channel");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

3. `C` listens on the port `6003`, and responds `B` with message `M2`:

```
// C.java

import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;

public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create Boss group : receiving client connection
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        // create work group: network read and communication
        EventLoopGroup workGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        // create start class
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();

        try {
            bootstrap.group(bossGroup, workGroup) // set thread group
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class) //set channel
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024) // set the number of thread connections
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new CHandler());
                        }
                    });
            System.out.println("----- C is online -----");
            ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.bind(6003).sync();
            channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

}
```

```
// CHandler.java

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;

public class CHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
        System.out.println("Receive from B: " + buf.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        // C responds with M2
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("M2", CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

My idea is to pass the `AB channel context` to the `BCHandler.java`, which receives the response from `C`, and then uses the AB channel to send back to `A`, **but it seems that A cannot receive the M2 at the end**. Thanks a lot if you can provide help!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what needs to be realized is a **Proxy Server** using Netty, so this [example](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy) can solve the problem and it works for me.